# Sum previous value in hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Basically I´ve got a hash and I would like to sum the current value with the previous.

i.e

what I have

```
hash = {:a=>5, :b=>10, :c=>15, :d=>3}
```

The result that I want

```
{:a=>5, :b=>15, :c=>30, :d=>33}
```

Comment: beware of your ruby version

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
hash.inject(0) { |s, (k, v)| hash[k] = s + v }
# => 33
hash
# => {:a=>5, :b=>15, :c=>30, :d=>33}
```

If you want to preserve the original hash, you can use `each_with_object` instead:

```
hash.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), h| h[k] = v + (h.values.last||0)  }
# => {:a=>5, :b=>15, :c=>30, :d=>33}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following will return a new hash instance:

```
hash.each_with_object({}) { |(key, val), new_hash| new_hash[key] = val + (new_hash.values.last||0)  }
```